# ng-show not never shows

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Following code always evaluates Top contributors as true asn Contributors as false. I can see the member.price and member.amount change? Anyone have an Idea what I am doing wrong?

```
<md-virtual-repeat layout-wrap class="toast" ng-repeat="member in members| filter:searchText | orderBy:orderByFunction" >
    <div class="subtitle"  ng-show="parseInt(member.price) <= parseInt(member.amount)" >
        <h2> CONTRIBUTORS {{member.price}} -- {{member.amount}}</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="subtitle"  ng-hide="parseInt(member.amount) <= parseInt(member.price)" >
        <h2> TOP CONTRIBUTORS  {{member.price}} -- {{member.amount}}</h2>
    </div>
```

so I started like this:

```
  <md-virtual-repeat layout-wrap class="toast" ng-repeat="member in members| filter:searchText | orderBy:orderByFunction" >
                                    <div class="subtitle"  ng-show="showContrib(member) == 1" >
                                        <h2> CONTRIBUTORS {{member.price}} -- {{member.amount}}</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="subtitle"  ng-hide="showTop(member) == 1" >
                                        <h2> TOP CONTRIBUTORS  {{Number(member.price)}} -- {{Number(member.amount)}}</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <md-whiteframe class="md-whiteframe-z3 frieed" style="margin:6px; padding: 19px;" flex-sm="35" flex-gt-sm="25" flex-gt-md="20" layout layout-align="center center">
                                        {{ member.amount}}
                                    </md-whiteframe>
                                </md-virtual-repeat>
```

with this js code:

```
   $scope.showTop = function(member){
        if($scope.topShow == 1){

            return 0;
        }
        if(parseInt(member.price) < parseInt(member.amount)){
    console.log('came here price');
             $scope.topShow = 1;
            return 1;

        }
        return 0;

};
    $scope.showContrib = function(member){
         $scope.conShow = 1;
//        console.log('price='+member.price+"amount"+member.amount);
        if($scope.conShow == 1){
            return 0;
        }
        if(parseInt(member.price) == parseInt(member.amount)){
           $scope.conShow = 1;
            return 1;

        }
        return 0;

};
```

Then I switch to the first part to try to troubleshoot.

Comment: I don't think you can use `parseInt` in an expression.  It's a JavaScript function, not a `$scope` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not use parseInt, instead I would like to use *1 to make it int.

```
<div class="subtitle"  ng-show="member.price*1 <= member.amount*1" >
    <h2> CONTRIBUTORS {{member.price}} -- {{member.amount}}</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: I like *1, sneak way but useful

Comment: This is the answer I used for my original question I would +1 you too but my reputation is not sufficient yet.

Comment: great to help you bro, please remind to accept the answer, that is ok too :)

Answer (score 2):

`parseInt` won't work in the view.

View works only on scope's property.

Create a comparer method on scope then call it from view.

Try like this

```
$scope.isGreater=function(a,b){
  return parseInt(a) <= parseInt(b);
}
```

view

```
<div class="subtitle"  ng-show="isGreater(member.price,member.amount)" >
    <h2> CONTRIBUTORS {{member.price}} -- {{member.amount}}</h2>
</div>
<div class="subtitle"  ng-hide="isGreater(member.amount, member.price)" >
    <h2> TOP CONTRIBUTORS  {{member.price}} -- {{member.amount}}</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `parseInt` as it is in your template.

Only elements(functions, variables) belonging to the scope of the controller can be used in the controller's template.

For using `parseInt` in the template, assign `window` object's `parseInt` to the controller's scope:

```
$scope.parseInt = window.parseInt;
```